# @distinctUnionOfOrderedSets equivalent to @distinctUnionOfArrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, kvc

I have an array of `foos` and each foo has a `NSOrderedSet` of `bars`. I want to get an array of all the distinct existent bars ids (each bar has a property called `objectID`).

Since there is no `@distinctUnionOfOrderedSets` I can do it with:

```
[foos valueForKeyPath:@"bars.objectID.@distinctUnionOfArrays.self"]
```

And it works, but since the bars are in a `NSOrderedSet` I get multiple times this error:

> -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray

Is there a way to do this without the error? Is it safe to leave like this?

Comment: Suggested: Use NSOrderedSet's array method in the keypath? `[foos valueForKeyPath:@"bars.array.objectID.@distinctUnionOfArrays.self"]`.   Alas, didn't work.